# Array with datarows

Tags: c#, arrays, datagrid, pocketpc

I have a datagrid and its datasource is a select from a table on a database.

Once I read the table and show the data on my grid, the rows in dababase are deleted
(but aaall my data is shown on my grid). After some changes, and add and delete information, I need to save these new rows in a new table!

I'm trying to read my datagrid but I don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
//fill my grid
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
conn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source =" + 
    (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)) + 
    "\\MOB.sdf;Password=acwef;Persist Security Info=False;");
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABDATAREG   ", conn);
da.Fill(ds, "TABDATAREG   ");
DivDup.dtgGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;


//and here, I'm trying to read
foreach (DataRow renglon in DivDup.dtgGrid.rows)//<--------- BUT IT DOESNT WORK
{
    arregloGrid[i, 0] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 0].ToString();//num_cía
    arregloGrid[i, 1] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 1].ToString();//num_tipo
    arregloGrid[i, 2] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 2].ToString();//num_activo
    arregloGrid[i, 3] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 3].ToString();//sub_num_act
    //posicion i
    arregloGrid[i, 4] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 4].ToString();//marca
    arregloGrid[i, 5] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 5].ToString();//modelo
    arregloGrid[i, 6] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 6].ToString();//serie
    arregloGrid[i, 7] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 7].ToString();//descripción
    arregloGrid[i, 8] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 8].ToString();//porcentaje
    arregloGrid[i, 9] = DivDup.dtgGrid[i, 9].ToString();//costo/importe
    i++;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `BUT IT DOESN'T WORK`, what does this mean?

Comment: MVS says: "Error 5 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid' no contiene una definición de 'rows' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'rows' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid' (¿falta una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?) "

Comment: Please edit your post to include more information, like this error message. And, if you can, write the English version.

Comment: Probably it needs something like "Read()" to fetch data or, its null at the time so the second pass will yield the rows so you should check for a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue:

1. You are looking for DataRow in [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. You are not using DataRow inside the loop.

Problem can be seen here in this loop:

```
foreach (DataRow renglon in DivDup.dtgGrid.rows)
{

}
```

This can be done like this:

```
foreach (DataRow renglon in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
         //here you can use renglon 
}
```

**Here is how you could traverse through datagrid**:

```
int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
int colCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;

for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) 
{ 
    for(int col = 0; col < colCount; col++) 
    { 
        arregloGrid[row, col] = DivDup.dtgGrid[row, col].ToString();                  
    } 
}
```

Please note above code is not tested.

Comment: **It works** @Hassan Nisar, **You rules! Thank You so much!**